# how to solve "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client" in this code "requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Params"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I used ckeditor for getting text from user. this field name is "Body" and in model is allowhtml.
For encrypted hidden redux used [like this](http://heartysoft.com/ashic/blog/2010/03/encrypted-hidden-with-salt/)

and i have an error : A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client
error is in DecryptingControllerFactory :

```
using System;
```

using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Labkhand.Helpers
{
    public class DecryptingControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        private readonly IEncryptSettingsProvider _settings;

```
    public DecryptingControllerFactory()
    {
        _settings = new EncryptSettingsProvider();
    }

    public override IController CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        var parameters = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Params;
        var encryptedParamKeys = parameters.AllKeys.Where(x => x.StartsWith(_settings.EncryptionPrefix)).ToList();

        IRijndaelStringEncrypter decrypter = null;

        foreach (var key in encryptedParamKeys)
        {
            if (decrypter == null)
            {
                decrypter = GetDecrypter(requestContext);
            }

            var oldKey = key.Replace(_settings.EncryptionPrefix, string.Empty);
            var oldValue = decrypter.Decrypt(parameters[key]);
            if (requestContext.RouteData.Values[oldKey] != null)
            {
                if (requestContext.RouteData.Values[oldKey].ToString() != oldValue)
                    throw new ApplicationException("Form values is modified!");
            }
            requestContext.RouteData.Values[oldKey] = oldValue;
        }

        if (decrypter != null)
        {
            decrypter.Dispose();
        }

        return base.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
    }

    private IRijndaelStringEncrypter GetDecrypter(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var decrypter = new RijndaelStringEncrypter(_settings, requestContext.GetActionKey());
        return decrypter;
    }

}
```

}

and error is this line :

```
var parameters = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Params;
```

if i give html value to Body field in controler i dont get error. 
how to solve this problem

Comment: Bind to your model in the post method (and apply the `[AllowHtml]` attribute to the relevant property

Comment: [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
        [Display(Name = "متن مقاله")]
        [AllowHtml]
        public string Body { get; set; }